# Perl else error

Tags: perl, if-statement, math

Hello I am new to programming in perl I am trying to make a number adder (math) but it gives me 1 error here's my code:

```
sub main {
    print("First: ");
    $num1 = <STDIN>;
    print("Second: ");
    $num2 = <STDIN>;

    $answer = $num1 + $num2;
    print("$answer")
} else {
    print("You have entered invalid arguments.")
}
main;
```

now obviously its not done but I get an error on ONLY else here is the error:

```
C:\Users\aries\Desktop>"Second perl.pl"
syntax error at C:\Users\aries\Desktop\Second perl.pl line 9, near "} else"
Execution of C:\Users\aries\Desktop\Second perl.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

please help (also I tried googling stuff still error)

Comment: You've got an `else` with no `if`

Comment: I am new to perl I am use to python can you send me a tutorial link to watch and learn how its done

Comment: a semi-colon is missing after `print("$answer")`.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Not necessarily, since it's the last instruction of the block.

Comment: I haven't seen the missing `if (...){`

Comment: Casimir et Hippolyte I noticed I just put a semi-colon there but that did not help with the issue.

Comment: @AriesFangz There are plenty of Perl tutorials you can find online. (have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/perl/info)). You should really go through the basics. (By the way, I'm pretty sure you can't put an `else` without an `if` before in python either)

Comment: @AriesFangz What you *might* have meant is something like `if (looks_like_number($num1) and looks_like_number($num2)){$answer=$num1+$num2;print"$answer"}else{...}` (`looks_like_number` is in [`Scalar::Utils`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar/Util.html) core module). But go through some book, tutorial or something first anyway!

Comment: @AriesFangz since you don't really know Perl yet, you probably won't understand why, but always start your perl programs with `use strict; use warnings;`.

Comment: Really? okay thanks :D

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte The semi-colon after `print("$answer")` is optional as it's the last statement in a block. Obviously, it's a very silly idea to omit it, but that's not going to stop the code from working.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're new to Perl, I recommend you add strict and warnings at the top of your scripts. This will help identify common problems and potentially dangerous code.

The main problem with your code is that you've appended the else statement to your subroutine. Here is an example of your code as I think you intended it to be:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number);

sub main {

    print 'First :'; 
    my $num1 = <STDIN>;

    print 'Second: ';
    my $num2 = <STDIN>;

    if( looks_like_number($num1) && looks_like_number($num2) ) {

        my $answer = $num1 + $num2;
        print "$answer\n";
    }
    else {
        die 'You have entered invalid arguments.';
    }
}

main();
```

There are a few things I should note here about the differences between Perl and Python that I think will help you understand Perl better.

1. Unlike Python, Perl doesn't care about white space. It uses curly braces and semi-colons to indicate the end of blocks and statements and will happily ignore any white space that isn't in quotes.
2. The else statement appended to the subroutine won't work because Perl isn't designed to evaluate code blocks that way. A subroutine is simply a named code block that can be called at any other point in the script. Any error handling will need to be done inside of the subroutine rather than to it.
3. Perl is very context-sensitive and doesn't make a solid distinction between strings and integers in variables. If you write $var_a = 1, Perl will read it as an integer. $var_b = '1', it will read it as a string. But, you can still add them together: $var_c = ($var_a + $var_b), and Perl will make $var_c = 2.

   This is another reason the else statement would not work as you've written it. Python would throw an error if you try to add non-integers, but Perl will just figure out how to combine them, and give you the result. If you try to add a letter and a number, Perl still won't fail, but it will warn you if you put "use warnings;" at the top of your script.

   In the example, and as Dada mentioned, you can use the looks_like_number() method from the Scalar::Utils module to evaluate the variables as you had intended.
4. Apart from the syntax, if/else statements work the same way in Perl as in Python. The else-if is slightly different as is has an extra s:

   if (condition) {
       ...
   }
   elsif (other condition) {
       ...
   }
   else {
       ...
   }
5. In Perl, it's good practice to assign lexical scope to variables using the **my** function. Since Perl is so context-sensitive, this can help prevent unexpected behavior when moving between different scopes.
6. Single- and double-quotes have different uses in Perl. Single-quotes are read literally and double-quotes are interpolated, so if you want to combine variables and text together, you can skip concatenating the strings and just do: **print "Got variable: $var\n";**
7. Lastly, note that I added parentheses after the main subroutine call. This is another best practice to make it clearer that you are calling a subroutine as opposed to it being a bare word or a bad variable name.

Comment: so in python example you do while True: you must do 4 white spaces for the code to work but in perl this is not needed

Comment: Exactly. Technically, you can strip out all white space in a perl script and, so long as the braces and semi-colons are in the right places, the script will run just fine. Not that anyone would actually do that, of course. :) There's actually a command-line script called [perltidy](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Perl-Tidy/bin/perltidy) whose only job is to format perl code so it's easier to read. It has some customization options, but I've found the default setting work well.